# Vue - Compile other folder outside of /src in Vue.js project

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-cli-3

I have a regular Vue.js project (created using v3.0.3) that uses WebSockets. Also in the project root is the `/server` folder which has the Node.js code that houses the multi-player aspect and socket code.

However, since the folder `/server` is independent of the `/src` folder from the Vue.js project, how do I make use of the Vue CLI webpack config and add babel compiling (using Webpack) to appropriately compile both the `/src`

[image]

https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#simple-configuration

Comment: What's a _"Node.js folder"_? What **exactly** would you like the result of this to be?

Comment: Can you show you project structure?

Comment: Wow this question is so confusing… First you should confirm that you want to build a server-side script, because usually Vue is used only for client-side (but with Nuxt you can also build a server-side service). Then explain why you absolutely need webpack for that: usually server-side script is not bundled. With 5k rep we would expect much more details from your question.

Comment: @ghybs I have changed my wording of the question. I apologize for the atrocious grammar. I know that server-side is not bundled with the Vue.js project which is why `/src` and `/server` are separate.

Comment: Hi, it is a little bit clearer now indeed. So you want to transpile your server code using the same webpack config as the Vue project? First of all, why do you need transpilation? Server code runs on the machine of your choice, with known Node.js version supporting desired ES syntax. See the total difference with client code that runs on remote machine and arbitrary browser and version, with unknown ES support, hence the need for transpilation for client code.

Comment: Well, I'd like to be able to do `import` instead of `require` on my Node.js scripts along with other things needed that webpack/babel support.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to import **babel-cli** and just *compile/run* like so:

```
./node_modules/.bin/nodemon --exec babel-node --presets env,stage-2 server.js
```

and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you should add `.babelrc` file and declare `presets`, `env` options and etc into it.

I don't know why you don't eject, because of access to `webpack` configuration. In the webpack config, you can declare your `src` folder or exclude other folders like `node_modlules` or your custom `server` folder.

For example, see webpack config for your issue:

```js
module.exports = {
  ~~~
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: ['node_modules', 'server'],
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
          },
        ],
      },
            ~~~
```

And see a sample `.babelrc` file:

```js
{
  "presets": [
    "es2015",
    "es2016",
    "es2017",
    "env",
    "stage-0"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "transform-class-properties",
    "transform-object-rest-spread",
      [
        "transform-runtime",
        {
          "helpers": true,
          "polyfill": true,
          "regenerator": true
        }
      ]
    ],
    "env": {
      "development": {
        "compact": false
      }
    }
  }
```

Then you should use your webpack commands to build:

```
webpack -p --config ./webpack.production.config.js
```